# Unzip a file Asyncronously in windows phone async

Tags: windows-phone-8, unzip

How can I unzip a file asynchronously to Isolated Storage? My zip file is in Isolated Storage, and I want to wait until the unzip operation has completed.
I am using SharpzipLib and SharpGIS, but I haven't seen any support for async unzip.
Also, I have to handle unzipping of large files, so out of memory exceptions also need to be handled. Are there any examples or suitable links to do it in an async way?